# How much content is in the common sense, according to Marvin Minsky?

Tags: epistemology, philosophy-of-mind

I remember watching, years ago, a lecture by (or an interview of) [Marvin Minsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvin_Minsky), in which he gave a numerical estimate of how much information was in the common sense. He stated that the common sense consists of *X many* facts or rules (My recollection of the actual number is vague)

What might that video be called, and did he write any papers with such a numerical estimate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some numbers can be found [in the wiki article on Cyc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyc):

> The back-of-the-envelope calculations by Doug, Alan, and their colleagues (including Marvin Minsky, Allen Newell, Edward Feigenbaum, and John McCarthy) indicated that that effort would require between 1000 and 3000 person-years of effort

and

> The Cyc knowledge base... as of 2017 is about 24.5 million [rules and assertions] and has taken well over 1,000 person-years of effort to construct."

Also see [Minsky's book, The Emotion Machine](http://web.media.mit.edu/%7Eminsky/eb6.html):

> This suggests that in each important realm, one might know perhaps a million things. But while it is easy to think of a dozen such realms, it is hard to think of a hundred of them. This suggests that a machine that does humanlike reasoning might only need a few dozen millions of items of knowledge

with the footnote

> This discussion is adapted from my introduction to Semantic Information Processing, MIT Press, 1969.